# How do I embed HTML in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, html, microsoft-word-2013, embedding

I'd like to embed an online map inside of a Word document for my geography task in school. I have the code for an iframe of a map at www.arcgis.com.

How do I insert it in the document? I'm using Word 2013.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: @DaveRook Yes, I found a good solution: I embedded it as an online video. It will popup when clicked and will be interactive. Insert -> Online Video -> paste embedding code.

Comment: Wanted to answer my own solution but I don't have enough points here at superuser

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the HTML code of the iframe to Word but the online map won't show up as Word can't display the output of HTML code like a web browser.

Comment: A web server doesn't display the HTML, a web browser however does.